# Shell script to Unzip and Enter directory

Tags: shell-script, tar

I am working on two shell scripts. The first accepts a number and a path. Enters said path, does and md5sum of all files then packages the files into a tar.gz.

The second script accepts a tar.gz, extracts the contents then enters the directory. My issue is entering the directory. I am running the command `tar -xzvf "$FILE"`, how can I get the output of the `tar` command? I attempted to

```
PATH=tar -xzvf "$FILE" | sed -e 's@/.*@@' | uniq
cd "$PATH"
```

But this does not seem to work. My second attempt is as follows:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "An upgrade package must be supplied."
else
    FILE=$1
    if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
        tar -xzvf "$FILE" 
        FOLDER="${FILE/.tar.gz/""}"
        cd "$FOLDER"
        if md5sum --status -c sums.txt && echo OK; then
            ./upgrade.sh
        else
        echo "md5sum check was not successful, cannot upgrade"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

This gives me a bad substitution error.

I can fix the bad substitution error, then it hangs at `cd`

Comment: Do not use PATH as your a variable. It is a special variable known to the OS, and it have a predefined meaning.

Comment: Noted, I will update that.

Comment: if `$FILE` contains desired directory, I would suggest `FOLDER="$(basename $FILE .tar.gz)"` to get basename of $FILE striped of `.tar.gz` suffixe. (note that this will break if $FILE contains space)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve. `tar -xzvf "$FILE"` will extract all contents of the archive and list all files. What do you want to do with the output? Your code makes assumptions about the archive's contents, e.g. that the archive contains a directory corresponding to its basename. Please specify all preconditions in your question.

Comment: @Archemar this works well! Thank you for this. I can accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: To make what Bodo says a bit clearer - it could unpack to a single file or multiple directories.